# Cannot run Jekyll (macOS Sierra) even with bundle exec

Tags: ruby, jekyll, github-pages, jekyll-bootstrap

Having all sorts of problems with Jekyll after upgrading to macOS Sierra (10.12). Running `jekyll build` fails with this error (this has long happened to me): `/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:35:in block in setup: You have already activated colorator 1.1.0, but your Gemfile requires colorator 0.1. Prepending`bundle exec`to your command may solve this. (Gem::LoadError)`.

In the past running `bundle exec jekyll serve` has fixed this problem, but now when I run that, I get the error:

`Liquid Exception: cannot load such file -- rouge in _posts/2015-12-20-welcome-to-jekyll.markdown
bundler: failed to load command: jekyll (/usr/local/bin/jekyll)
LoadError: cannot load such file -- rouge`

First thought was to try to reinstall rouge, so ran `sudo gem install rouge`, but that didn't do anything. Also tried uninstalling and reinstalling jekyll. I also checked the `/usr/local/bin/jekyll` path, and jekyll is in there.  Not really sure how to fix this problem (or what the problem is). thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running `jekyll` commands, try using `bundle` instead. This `bundle` prefix will load the proper gemset as specified in `Gemfile`.

in the root project directory try:

```
bundle install
bundle exec jekyll build && bundle exec jekyll serve
```

Comment: Yeah this is what has fixed my problems in the past, but now it just throws a new error (see above)

Comment: Is `jekyll build` being run outside of `bundle`? that can be a problem

Comment: What does `bundle install` output? The output above looks like it hasn't been run - hard to tell though.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across the same problem and fixed it.

First, do this

- sudo gem install bundler
- bundle install

At last, intall jekyll again

- sudo gem install jekyll